# JPA repository deleteById method not working for several tests

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, automated-tests

I have an entity

```
@Entity
@Builder
@Data
@Table(name = "test_entities")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TestEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "entity_id")
    Long entityId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    String description;

    @Column(name = "enttp_enttp_id")
    Long entityTypeId;

    @Column(name = "start_status_id")
    Long entityInitialStatusId;

    @Column(name = "final_status_id")
    Long entityFinalStatusId;

    @Column(name = "is_default")
    Boolean isDefault;

    @Column(name = "navi_date")
    LocalDateTime naviDate;

    @Column(name = "navi_user")
    String naviUser;

    @Column(name = "del_user")
    String delUser;

    @Column(name = "del_date")
    LocalDateTime delDate;
}
```

and I have a JPA repository

```
@Transactional
public interface EntityRepository extends JpaRepository<TestEntity, Long>  {
    void deleteById(Long entityId);

}
```

and I have some tests that create some entities in a DB. After creating the entity I delete the created entity

```
@Slf4j
public class CreateEntityTest extends E2EAbstractTest{
    @Autowired
    public EntityRepository entityRepository;
    @Test
    public void createEntity(){

        log.info("Send POST /createEntity request ");
//some code
        JSONAssert.assertEquals(expectedResponseBody, actualResponseBody, JSONCompareMode.LENIENT);
        entityRepository.deleteById(entityId);
    }

    @Test

    public void createEntityGetObject(){

        log.info("Send POST /createEntuty request. getObject=true");
        //some code
        JSONAssert.assertEquals(expectedResponseBody, actualResponseBody, JSONCompareMode.LENIENT);
        entityRepository.deleteById(entityId);
    }
```

When I run only one test the entity deletes from the database perfectly. When I run the whole test class (several tests in a row), the entity doesn't delete.

Why is it so? How can I fix this problem

UPD:Adding @Transactional to the test class and to each test didn't work.

I enabled   `jpa: show-sql: true` in application.yml
and I see only select in log but no delete query

```
Hibernate: select e1_0.entity_id,e1_0.del_date,e1_0.del_user,e1_0.description,e1_0.final_status_id,e1_0.start_status_id,e1_0.enttp_enttp_id,e1_0.is_default,e1_0.name,e1_0.navi_date,e1_0.navi_user from entity_id e1_0 where e1_0.entity_id=?
```